# Empty post value : CodeIgniter

Tags: file-upload, codeigniter-3

While uploading the file through codeigniter, I am getting the following error:
My file upload result is:

[image: CI File Upload Error]

My Controller function is below:

```
public function Upload files($data='')
    {   
        ini_set("display_errors",1); // I added so it would help me show errors
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        print_r($_POST);exit('I am in the tp');
        $config['upload_path']          = 'assets/images/uploads/';
        //$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        //$config['max_size']             = 100;
        //$config['max_width']            = 1024;
        //$config['max_height']           = 768;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);exit('The first loop'); 
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                }
         else
        {

        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        print_r($data);exit();
        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
```

And my view file:

```
                                <div id="Upload_div"> 
                                <?php //echo $error;?>   
                                <form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/Admin/Upload_files/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                  <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
                                  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="userfile"><br><br>
                                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                                </form>
                                </div>
```

Can anyone help me figure out why post value is empty?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` does not contain any file data.

Remove the line

```
 print_r($_POST);exit('I am in the tp');
```

And then tell us what happens.

Comment: Hey I got cleared with this issue after checking what is inside the $_POST and fixed it. Thank you